# Uses of "in such .....as to"

Tags: word-order, word-form

I would appreciate it if anybody indicates the usage of **in such ......... as to**. I knew that if I would provide context, it might easy for experts to say something about my query. But I'm afraid to say that no context is available. Before posting this thread at this website, I asked one of my friends about **in such ....... as to**. He told me that it may be used to represent a potential result, not a result that has already occurred. But he was not sure.

By the way, are the sentences which I have written above correct?

Comment: I don't recognize the expression as such. Is there perhaps a longer version that's been cut off? Is the missing part a noun? Do you mean as in: "*in such **donkey** as to*"? That has no meaning in English. But it might if we build the sentence longer.

Comment: Please, recheck my query. I have edited it.

Comment: Yes, if you have enough time, please make a longer, or a complete sentence.

Comment: Hehe, you accidentally removed the style changes I've put... Or was it intentional?

Comment: Your query is still not answerable. You need to specify if it's a noun or something in the place of dots. As it is now, I can't recognize it from proper English (but it sounds like a distorted fragment of something that **was** correct but isn't anymore. Do you mean as in "*in such **case** as to...*"? You don't need to provide the **context** but you will need to give an **example**.

Comment: I cannot understand what you have said. What did I change accidentally?

Comment: Never mind. It's OK. But please provide an **example** (not context), to clarify. Otherwise, I'd say your friend is mistaken.

Comment: No, I didn't mean "in such as to". You may put any word or words group between "in such" and "as to" that is able to make sense when it will be put in a complete sentence.

Comment: I wanted to give an example. But unfortunately I didn't find any example, and I think, the experts of this site are able to discuss the usage of it, even if they are not provided any example......ha ha ha    ...

Comment: Yes, we are. And so I did. The short answer is "no", it's not correct. Unless we're missing something (hence the request for an example). We're awesome expters but we **can** make small mistakes, hehehe.

Comment: Would you like to tell the meaning of "Yes, we are. And so I did"?

Comment: You said: "*the experts of this site are able to discuss...*". So I made a joke: "*yes, we are*" meaning "*yes, we are **able to discuss***". Then "*and so I did*" meaning "*I'm an expert and I did **discuss it***".

Comment: Sorry Konrad Viltersten. I was late to response for my dinner. I'm extremly sorry.

Comment: It's all right. But you might want to go through all the other questions you've had. There are a lot of them that need accepting the answers. I'll respond to the other question soon. Next year, though, probably, hehe.

Comment: For your information, "such as....as to" is not a form in English at all and you have selected an answer that is full of mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there's a uncommon usage that I'm not familiar with, I'd say it's wrong. When I try to make sense of the following:

> ...in such **case** as to...

I can't think of anything that would make sense. We can say:

> I'll visit a new club tonight and **in such place as** that, I'll score for sure.

but that's not following the *to* part of your pattern. Or we could say:

> I won't dance because **such action as to** dance makes me look like an idiot.

but that misses the *in* part of your pattern. So I doubt that it's correct to use it the way your friend suggested but you're not far off.

Comment: in such case....as to is not a "thing" in English.

Comment: @Lambie Oh, that was a surprise. Might be my prejudice, which I apologize for, but I did not expect a woman. That got me curious. Regrettably, your blurb only told be that you prefer to keep an air of mystery about you.   :)

Answer (score 0):

"in (with) such.........as to"

I have some examples of this construction

> The man was laughing with such gusto as to frighten the child
>
> The gift was given in such jest as to amuse the crowd

Not brilliant examples, but you get the idea....

(The man laughed so heartily that he frightened the child; 
the gift was given in such a funny way that it amused the crowd)

Comment: Yes, but I think one need to point out that the question isn't not a form in English. "in such ....as to". You might want to say something about that.

Comment: @Lambie Please don't take this comment as an ofence or aggression on my part and I do apologies if it comes out that way. I noticed that you make remarks on the answers given being (politely) criticizing. While the critique is encouraged and welcome, I noticed that in your comment, you have a grammatical error (*one need**s** to...) and a double negation ("isn't not..."). While certainly possible that those are but typos, I also notice some word choices suggestion that you refer to **colloquial** English, being the common way but not the only. May I enquire to your academic background, please?

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for clarifying your "credentials". And hats off for not taking offense. Such a question might be perceived as infectious by certain people. The original question was asked New Year's Eve over four years ago so I guess the OP doesn't care anymore. However, for the correctness sake, feel free to edit the shazoo of my answer to make it proper. I trust your judgement.   :)